# Using a control to direct where a variable gets set

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, variables, controls

I'm just starting out, still working on improving my little poker calculator. What I'm aiming to do is have the controls on the right (green) set the float value of the middle textboxes. The hitch is that I want to do it to only the textbox that the red arrow is at. On the flipside if I move the red arrow I want it to reset the green arrow to whatever is in the textboxes where red stops.

Hope that makes sense.

I have action methods for all of the sliders and red returns exactly a value from 1-8 depending on where it stops (Currently 1)

The textboxes are all named call_1, call_2 etc for the time being but I don't know how make a method declaration for anything but exactly the name I need. Because the Red Arrow returns 1-8 that _1, _2 etc would be the way to go. It would also be nice to use this for loop counts as well in a few places.

http://img833.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20110319at723.png/

Thanks guys, I really really appreciate everything Overflow has done so far!

Cheers

Graham

Edit :

What I am trying to do is with the textboxes is to use the red slider which gives me an int of X (1-8) in this fashion.

```
[call_x setFloatValue:someValue]
```

As X changes the destination changes as well. If I can get help with this I can manipulate it to do everything else I want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish but from looking at your screenshot I would bet that key-value observing could help you.  It looks like you are dealing with the copious amounts of glue code that ends up cluttering up controller classes. This glue code manages updating your model when a view changes, and vice versa.  It also defines the logic among views (i.e update a text box when a slider changes etc).

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html
Key-Value observing allows you to receive a callback when some value in another object changes.  In this callback you update anything else that needs it.  Taking this one step further is bindings in cocoa.  Bindings literally bind the property of one object to the value of another.  You should investigate these technologies to reduce the amount of boring glue code you have to manage yourself.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I read about KVC awhile back trying to sum an array and never explored it. I'll read into that and I have used bindings in a few places just in IB to keep things in line. I edited my original to help the understanding a bit hopefully.